# Text field only allowing 1 character at a time on macOS 10.12

Tags: macos, textfield, macos-sierra, nsnotification

My app was working fine for years, but now, when a user tries to input some text inside the text field, it only takes the first character and then exits the field.

This is very annoying. I've been searching for weeks. I've Googled this, no one seems to have that problem but me.

The log shows that controlTextDidChange: is being called, but I have no code that relates to this field.

Has anything changed in 10.12 and I'm not aware of ? Apple's documentation does not mention any changes for this method.

Thanks!

Comment: have you tried to investigate this a little further ? I mean, log what's calling the notification or check if there's any action from the textfield. Are you using storyboard?

Comment: Well, yeah of course I did. I've been investiguating this for months, sometimes I've spent whole days on it, no result. It's been working fine for years and now on OS 10.12 it does this. So I'm pretty sure this is the reason why. I've googed this many times, no one has experience that it seems. Just trying to see if someone else had, and to get a new path to solving this.

Comment: And no, I'm not using storyboards (mac app), and the only action from the textfield is the user typing stuff in it, I'm just watching for specific keywords to appear and modify stuff. But now, everytime the user types one character, it's like the app does a return right after and commits only this new character to the field. It is quite annoying.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, finally found the answer. In the Bindings, the "Continuous update value" was selected for the Value Binding with the Array Controller. I guess it had a different behaviour in past OS versions. All is well now. Took me months to find this!!